# Statistical theory proof intuition (UMVU estimators)

Tags: self-study, intuition, estimators, mathematical-statistics

I've been working through this problem in Theoretical Statistics by Keener, but could not solve it. I looked up the answer and I do understand why it's correct, but I don't understand what intuition would have led to it.

The question is:

> Suppose $X$ is an exponential random variable with density $p_\theta(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x}, x > 0 $ and $p_\theta(x) = 0$ otherwise. Find the UMVU estimator of $1 / (1 + \theta)$.

and the solution given is

> If we assume $\delta$ is unbiased and can be written as a power series $\delta(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \dots ,$ then by Fubini’s theorem we anticipate
>   $$E_\theta\delta(X) = \int_0^\infty \left ( \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_nx^n \right ) \theta e^{-\theta x} dx \\ = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\int_0^\infty c_nx^n\theta e^{-\theta x} dx = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n!c_n}{\theta^n}$$
>   by matching coefficients for powers of $1/θ$, $c_0 = 0$ and $c_n = (−1)^{n+1}/n!$,
>   n = 1, 2, . . . . This gives $δ = 1 − e^{−X}$. The steps in this derivation only
>   work if θ > 1, but it is easy to show directly that δ is unbiased. Because
>   the densities form a full rank exponential family, X is complete, and δ is
>   UMVU.

I understand in retrospect why this is correct, but I'm not sure what the process or intuition would be to arrive at such an answer independently.

Comment: There is not much intuition to be found behind a series expansion. Or the fact that $\mathbb{E}[\exp\{-X\}]=\theta/(1+\theta)$.

Comment: The next question is what do you do with an exponential sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$?

Comment: I suppose my question is more about what intuition about the problem would lead to thinking about series expansion as a possible solution. I understand the solution and why it's correct  but I would've never thought to look into series expansion while trying to solve it.

Comment: Series expansions rarely work with integrals, because it may end up with infinite terms. The exponential density is sort of the exception...

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> There is not much intuition to be found behind a series expansion. Or
>   the fact that $ \mathbb{E}[\exp\{-X\}]=\theta/(1+\theta)$.

– Xi'an

> I suppose my question is more about what intuition about the problem
>   would lead to thinking about series expansion as a possible solution.
>   I understand the solution and why it's correct but I would've never
>   thought to look into series expansion while trying to solve it.

– Iinferno1

> Series expansions rarely work with integrals, because it may end up
>   with infinite terms. The exponential density is sort of the
>   exception ...

– Xi'an